# How to Switch between Tables in MVC at runtime?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In the MVC project with Entity Framework, the Model has the class:

```
[Table("astrTableJan16")]
public class astrTable
{
[Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }   (...rest of variables)
```

In the database there is one table per month, so astrTableJan16, astrTableFeb16, and then going back, astrTableDec15 etc.  I had manually created the Tables from SQL Management Studio, copying the original table,

```
 SELECT * INTO astrTableNov15 FROM dbo.astrTable
```

Currently to use a different month, the [Table("")] entry is manually modified, and the project run (in the debugger), then the CRUD functions apply to that table.

The goal is to be able to switch between these tables at runtime, to have CRUD functionality for the user on a month they choose.  There will be a DropDown list control showing the available months, the user picks the month, and *that* specific  table is loaded and can be modified/saved.  Is this possible?

Have tried using Sql commands from

```
 using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

So far the data can be read in, but the db.SaveChanges() has to be redefined.

And hopefully it needs to keep just the ONE Model class definition if possible, otherwise the project will need one Model reference for each month, and if that's for 10 years there are many Models to define;  It can be done this way but I want to design it properly with reliability as the main goal.

Can the table be switched on the fly at runtime?  Or should there be one Model per month and the application references the table directly this way?

Comment: this is easier than adding a month column?.. you probably just want to use a stored procedure if you want to keep doing it this way

Comment: I can add a column, but for each month there are about 400 columns and almost 100 records, per month

Comment: you say the table name changes but not the properties, so every month table has the same columns?  so if you just added a month column to one table you would have 401 columns and only 12000 records?

Comment: even if you split the columns out into a key/value table that would only be around 4.8 million records for 10 years.. thats not a lot

Comment: right, what I do is change the table name in the Model for the month needed to be used, then run in the IDE, then the Edit/Create work on that table.  And the columns stay the same, just different data, each of the 100 (or less) records get updated for the month and saved.  Currently users only access the current month, how can adding the extra month col. be used?  am trying to picture it

Comment: There are many columns but they are all string.  Some are yes/no, others are numbers or a short sentence.  Good reliability for the user is the priority, it can be redesigned so as to allow months to be used; I thought the table being referenced could somehow be changed as its running, but it seems this isn't the case?

Comment: Sounds like you are using the database as a collection of spreadsheets.  You're going to make life very difficult on yourself.  Listen to the other commenters.. when the 'Ah Ha!' moment comes you'll never go back.

Answer (score 0):

- Add a month column to the table: `Month NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL` (string column).
  This is not a good data type, but its consistent with the rest of your table and I don't want to introduce additional concepts right now.
- Add a year column to the table: `Year INT NOT NULL`.

Then when you want to work with a particular month/year you ask the database for it like so:  (e.g. January 2016)

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Month = 'January' AND Year = 2016
```

Once you add the columns, you will want to merge each of your existing tables into a single table.  So lets say your tables, as they exist now, each have (the same) 400 columns.  Your new table will have 402 columns.  The data from each of your existing tables will stack in rows in the new table.

For example:
ExistingTableJan2015

> ID, Data ...
>   1,something
>   2,something else

and ExistingTableMar2015

> ID, Data ...
>   4,yadda
>   5,yada yada

Would merge into NewTable

> ID, Month, Year, data
>   1, January, 2015, something
>   2, January, 2015, something else
>   4, March, 2015, yada
>   5, March, 2015, yada yada

So now you have a single table that stores all your data and there is no need to switch tables at runtime.

Comment: Ok, almost an ah-ha moment;  I add these 2 Columns.  With the SELECT command it will read that table, but how can I write changes back to that same table?   The Edit [HttpPost] method has the db.SaveChanges(); How can I point it to the right table?  Sorry if I'm slow.

Comment: It would not let me add the not null columns to the existing table, but  thats a minor detail, am getting the SELECT * part working first

Comment: edited answer.  Keep asking questions if you need more help.

Comment: You would create a new table with the two new columns, not add them to the existing tables.

Comment: yes great, but the ID's will be duplicates, Im starting to get it, so 402 columns, each table had 100 (lets say) records each with an id of 1 to 100; Youre saying stack these all, for each month into one table but the IDs of each month are identical, how do they get grouped? hopefully not manually

Comment: If the IDs are just a key that doesn't tie to any other table/data, then when you merge your existing data into the new table you can safely ignore the imported IDs - make the ID column in the new table an `IDENTITY` (autonumber) column.  If the IDs DO matter for some other purpose then in the new table make the Primary Key a composite of ID, Month, and Year.

Comment: The merge process (of existing tables into the new table) is going to be a "manual" process.  Each table will need to be merged one at a time.  You can do this by hand via Management Studio, or write a program to automate it.  Either way you will need to parse the table name and insert the correct values for Month and Year for each merge operation.

Comment: I dont mind doing a merge one table at a time, but just worry about the size if it will slow down the response; the process, is it a JOIN statement?  new ID's are fine, the ID gets referenced as a placeholder it should be ok.  Is it a JOIN or UNION that adds each into a new table?